# Error: Error: read ECONNRESET Packages failed to restore

Tags: nuget-package-restore, azure-artifacts, azure-devops-server-2019

I am trying to restore NuGet packages from the Azure Artifacts feed with the task "Nuget restore" which is giving an error -

```
2020-03-17T06:16:01.923910Z Resolved from tool cache: 4.1.0

2020-03-17T06:16:01.939365Z Using version: 4.1.0

2020-03-17T06:16:01.924520Z Found tool in cache: NuGet 4.1.0 x64

2020-03-17T06:16:02.080668Z [command]C:\Windows\system32\chcp.com 65001

2020-03-17T06:16:02.007116Z Active code page: 65001

2020-03-17T06:16:02.012223Z Detected NuGet version 4.1.0.2450 / 4.1.0

2020-03-17T06:16:02.081611Z SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true

2020-03-17T06:16:04.157611Z ##[error]Error: Error: read ECONNRESET

2020-03-17T06:16:04.190260Z ##[error]Packages failed to restore
```

**Details** -

Server - Azure DevOps server 2019

Azure DevOps build pipeline

Azure Artifacts Feed - offline

Agent Version 2.144.2

**What I noticed** 
my "Nuget Restore" task is working well when my build machine is in the same LAN with azure DevOps server and giving an error with the different LAN's build machine.

I googled but did not find anything. some pages showing this error is because of the proxy, some page is showing version issue of NuGet.

Not getting what exactly the issue is. Can someone help with this?

Comment: You may check whether firewall is configured correctly on the different LAN's build machine.